# CEdit Warning when deleting content?

Tags: mfc

I have a CEdit box which has some pre-populated numbers.
When the user uses the backspace key to delete the content of the CEdit box, the following warning messagebox appears: 
"Please enter a valid number. Invalid numbers include: spaces, decimals, 0, +, -"

I would like to be able to backspace the entire content of the CEdit box without the warning box appearing. However, once entered, I would like to have the value checked that it is indeed a number.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

All the best
a.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using now?  There are several ways to handle this (eg. trapping ON_EN_UPDATE) and without seeing what you are doing now, it's difficult to comment.

Comment: Hi rrirower I do not have code, but I do modify the ON Change message. What should I put within the ON_EN_UPDATE? I do not specifically do any checks. It seems that MFC is doing the checks for me (to see if it is an integer)

Comment: It seems that MFC adds the check itself, and reports the condition via a MessageBox. This is great, however it is very annoying to the User if they delete the content of the CEdit box and get this warning message. Thus I would like to intercept this MessageBox before it appears. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any calls to DDV_xxxx functions in the DoDataExchange function? Those calls are optional and can produce the clumsy message boxes. You can do better by removing the DDV_ calls and doing the data validation yourself.

Comment: Hi ScottMcP-MVP, I am afraid I do not have any DDV_ calls (I do have DDX_ calls). Could you please suggest where else the data gets validated? (This is beginning to frustrate me).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I did this only once: I've extended CEdit class and ovverided the PretranslateMessage. Here's the code:

// .h

```
#pragma once

// CHexEdit

#define WM_RETURN_PRESSED WM_USER + 5
#define WM_NUMBER_INSERTED WM_USER + 6

class CHexEdit : public CEdit
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC( CHexEdit )
    public:
    CHexEdit();
    virtual ~CHexEdit();
    protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    public:
    afx_msg void OnKeyUp( UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags );
    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg );
};

// .cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HexEdit.h"
#include "Utils.h"

// CHexEdit

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC( CHexEdit, CEdit )

CHexEdit::CHexEdit()
{
}

CHexEdit::~CHexEdit()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CHexEdit, CEdit )
    ON_WM_KEYUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CHexEdit message handlers

BOOL CHexEdit::PreTranslateMessage( MSG* pMsg )
{
    bool bAFChars;
    bool b09Chars;
    bool bValidInput;
    bool bControlChars;
    BOOL bOK;

    if ( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN )
    {
        bAFChars = pMsg->wParam >= 'A' && pMsg->wParam <= 'F';
        bAFChars |= pMsg->wParam >= 'a' && pMsg->wParam <= 'f';
        b09Chars = pMsg->wParam >= '0' && pMsg->wParam <= '9';
        bValidInput = bAFChars || b09Chars;
        bControlChars = pMsg->wParam >= 0x08 && pMsg->wParam <= 0x2F;
        bControlChars = bControlChars || ( pMsg->wParam >= 0x5B && pMsg->wParam <= 0x5F );
        bControlChars = bControlChars || ( pMsg->wParam >= VK_NUMPAD0 && pMsg->wParam <= VK_NUMPAD9 );

        if ( bValidInput || bControlChars )
        {
          bOK = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
              bOK = FALSE;
        }

        if ( !bOK ) return TRUE;    // Non fare la pre-translate.
    }

    return CEdit::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

void CHexEdit::OnKeyUp(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    CString strValue;

    switch( nChar )
    {
    case VK_RETURN:
        /*GetParent()->PostMessage( WM_RETURN_PRESSED, 0, ( LPARAM )byNewValue );*/
        break;
    default:
        GetParent()->PostMessage( WM_NUMBER_INSERTED, 16 );
        break;
    }

    CEdit::OnKeyUp(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

Obviously you have to catch the message on your container class, but this should not be a problem. Hope this will help to solve your problem. Lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your response, I think I have a clearer picture.  By defining the field as an integer, you will get the built in MFC validation.  So, you can try adding DDV_ routines like Scott suggested, or, change the field type to a string (eg. CString) and do your own validation via the trapped messages that were mentioned earlier.  Either way should work, however, you'll get more flexibility if you validate the field via your own routines.

Comment: Hi That is exactly what I have done, and it works very well. Thank you all for your help.